Can I save a question on Staging Ground?
A question is in Staging Ground that I want to know the answer to. I hope it will be moved to the main site and answered.
Can I use the Saves feature for items in Staging Ground? I couldn't find the save button there.
I also couldn't find the button to move it to the main site either. Am I bad at finding stuff in the UI, is it hidden because I use a mobile platform; or maybe it doesn't exist?

Well, if that Question in the 'Staging Ground' is already "so interesting", then it's probably already fit for graduating to 'Main'. Why don't you approve it yourself,...? (That's the "Button to move it to the 'Main' Site"...) Or if it still needs some (minor) improvements, you can accompany/help the Asker toward bringing their Question "into shape", or edit it yourself so it can be approved...

"I couldn't find the button to move it to the main site either." there should be a pretty obvious widget at the right side with radio buttons for the various review options you can take. On smaller devices (mobile) it should be a sticky dropdown / select menu at the bottom of the page. Can you perhaps show us what you see via screenshot?

If you're unsure how to use the Staging Ground, it has its own section in the [help].

If the author is unfamiliar with how to promote the SG, we should proceed with caution, since the author given their reputation could promote the question themselves. I worry that due to the  authors personal interest in the question being answered their ability to judge the quality of the question within the SG might not be accurate. Especially without details

"follow" it (check for the link at the bottom of the question):

Then presumably you'd get notified if it gets promoted to the main site.
A "bookmark" feature wouldn't make a lot of sense, since SG items are meant to be transient by nature.

Are questions in the SG and in the main site not identical in their id? That would not make them transitory and bookmarking technically possible. Or what is an SG item?

I think that SG posts do not share the id with the question in main (if promoted). Look at this example: https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79317769

Okay then they effectively make a copy of the question. They could theoretically move bookmarks at this moment to the copied question but it would be extra effort. I somehow had assumed it was designed differently and questions would be moved not copied. But maybe there is an advantage of keeping a copy of the SG version after graduation.

Sure. All of that is beyond the scope of this question and answer, though.

Sure. Just commenting on your transient remark. I was a bit surprised. Questions seemed to be the only thing that is kind of stable around here (and user profiles maybe).
